# How to filter by timestamp of queued data in NiFi?

Tags: apache-nifi

How to sort with latest data on top (List Queue) in NiFi? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: it is sorted according to priority defined in queue. do you want to sort them for processing or just on the screen?

Comment: I need it to just view the data on screen with recent record on top

Answer (score 0):

You can change priority as follows

[image]

Comment: To improve accessability of your answer, please add a textual description. Compare [answer]. And maybe take the [tour].